# why live server to view "css" result in "vscode" wont work?

Tags: html, css, templates, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2012

I installed go "go live" for live server in "vscode" , but I cant see the result of my "css" code in live server. why live server to view "css" result in "vscode" wont work?
please help!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can only go live on HTML because CSS doesn't support Live server.